# What is "count" edge attribute in Networkx?

Tags: python, image-processing, networkx, graph-theory, scikit-image

I cannot understand what is the "count" attribute in the region adjacency graph computed by the following function: `skimage.future.graph.rag_boundary()`.

The "weight" attribute is explained but not the "count" one.

Even when reading the source code, I didn't understand what is it. Can someone help me ? Thank you

Here is the source:

```
def rag_boundary(labels, edge_map, connectivity=2):
    """ Comouter RAG based on region boundaries

    Given an image's initial segmentation and its edge map this method
    constructs the corresponding Region Adjacency Graph (RAG). Each node in the
    RAG represents a set of pixels within the image with the same label in
    `labels`. The weight between two adjacent regions is the average value
    in `edge_map` along their boundary.

    labels : ndarray
        The labelled image.
    edge_map : ndarray
        This should have the same shape as that of `labels`. For all pixels
        along the boundary between 2 adjacent regions, the average value of the
        corresponding pixels in `edge_map` is the edge weight between them.
    connectivity : int, optional
        Pixels with a squared distance less than `connectivity` from each other
        are considered adjacent. It can range from 1 to `labels.ndim`. Its
        behavior is the same as `connectivity` parameter in
        `scipy.ndimage.filters.generate_binary_structure`.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> from skimage import data, segmentation, filters, color
    >>> from skimage.future import graph
    >>> img = data.chelsea()
    >>> labels = segmentation.slic(img)
    >>> edge_map = filters.sobel(color.rgb2gray(img))
    >>> rag = graph.rag_boundary(labels, edge_map)

    """

    conn = ndi.generate_binary_structure(labels.ndim, connectivity)
    eroded = ndi.grey_erosion(labels, footprint=conn)
    dilated = ndi.grey_dilation(labels, footprint=conn)
    boundaries0 = (eroded != labels)
    boundaries1 = (dilated != labels)
    labels_small = np.concatenate((eroded[boundaries0], labels[boundaries1]))
    labels_large = np.concatenate((labels[boundaries0], dilated[boundaries1]))
    n = np.max(labels_large) + 1

    # use a dummy broadcast array as data for RAG
    ones = as_strided(np.ones((1,), dtype=np.float), shape=labels_small.shape,
                      strides=(0,))
    count_matrix = sparse.coo_matrix((ones, (labels_small, labels_large)),
                                     dtype=np.int_, shape=(n, n)).tocsr()
    data = np.concatenate((edge_map[boundaries0], edge_map[boundaries1]))

    data_coo = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (labels_small, labels_large)))
    graph_matrix = data_coo.tocsr()
    graph_matrix.data /= count_matrix.data

    rag = RAG()
    rag.add_weighted_edges_from(_edge_generator_from_csr(graph_matrix),
                                weight='weight')
    rag.add_weighted_edges_from(_edge_generator_from_csr(count_matrix),
                                weight='count')

    for n in rag.nodes():
        rag.node[n].update({'labels': [n]})

    return rag
```

Comment: Do you understand what `count_matrix` is?

Comment: This is the problem. I didn't understand what this matrix contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight matrix corresponds to the average of the pixel values at the boundaries between regions. The count matrix corresponds to the number of pixels along those boundaries. Thus, `rag[i][j]['count']` contains the number of pixels along the boundary of regions `i` and `j`.

The code uses some fancy [SciPy sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) tricks for efficiency. I (modestly ;) recommend Chapter 5 of Elegant SciPy (available free online at http://elegant-scipy.org) to learn more about those formats.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand now.
Thank you for the reading suggestion.